# How to install new RAM

Tags: memory

I'm considering of buy a new RAM for my notebook. At the moment I have a single 4GB RAM. The useful informations by `lshw` are:

```
description: Notebook
    product: SATELLITE PRO C70-A (PSCE7E)
    vendor: TOSHIBA
    version: PSCE7E-007007IT
    serial: 7D190479C
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Type1Family sku=PSCE7E uuid=E00C8196-E9FA-E211-B3D1-089E01D2162C
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Type2 - Board Product Name1
       vendor: Type2 - Board Vendor Name1
       physical id: 0
       version: Type2 - Board Version
       serial: Type2 - Board Serial Number
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.00
          date: 04/30/2013
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6592KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi


*-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 28
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM [empty]
         product: Empty
         vendor: Empty
         physical id: 0
         serial: Empty
         slot: DIMM0
    *-bank:1
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
         product: M471B5273CH0-YK0
         vendor: Samsung
         physical id: 1
         serial: E1500302
         slot: DIMM1
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

My questions are:

1. After buying the new RAM I have to simply put it in the slot and power on the PC then it will recognize it automatically?
2. Can I buy a 8GB RAM and install it beside the 4GB RAM I currently have or they have to be of the same size?
3. I have to choose a `DDR3` one, right?
4. The frequency of the new one has to be the same of the old one?

Comment: I would visit [Kingston.com](http://www.kingston.com/us/) or [crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/homepage) and see what memory is compatible with your system.

Comment: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner  works very well it will give you max your system can take and what type.

Comment: @Moab both sites give me the two options of buying a 4GB or a 8GB one. But can I have a 4GB and a 8GB (total 12GB)?

Comment: @Red, I found specifications for the exact model you asked about. You can take a look [here](http://www.toshiba.it/discontinued-products/satellite-pro-c70-a-11z/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. You can have RAM modules of different sizes. Per [specifications](http://www.toshiba.it/discontinued-products/satellite-pro-c70-a-11z/) your laptop supports up to 16Gb of RAM.
3. Yes. Per specifications your laptop uses DDR3 RAM modules.
4. Per specifications it has to be 1600Mhz.

Comment: In addition to this, you need SODIMM instead of regular modules.